# encrypt encrypted data

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I want to encrypt encrypted data  I used RSA encrytion. But when I encrypt encrypted data by using another public key. The error is "Unspecified error"

I think the issue from key size.

My key size is 1024 bit.

brief source code :

1. First Step : encrypt data by using RSA Public Key with key size 1024 bit

   ```
   byte[] encryptedData = RSAalg.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false);
   ```
2. Second Step : encrypt data by using another RSA Public Key with key size 1024 bit either

   ```
   byte[] encryptedData1 = RSAalg1.Encrypt(encryptedData, false);
   ```

The error shows in second step. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the padding you cannot encrypt 1024 bits of data (which is what `encryptedData` should be) with a 1024 bits key.

If you're using .NET and C# then Encrypt with `false` means you using PKCS#1 padding, which (from memory) will allow you to encrypt 117 bytes (not 128 bytes).

Note: you should not iterate the second encryption to get your results - but you should ask yourself why you want to encrypt this data twice with two keys (of the same key length). If you want more security then you should use a larger key (once). OTOH if you want more than one key to decrypt the data then you need a different strategy.

Comment: I want to make a secure e-voting by used tow keys with different persons .... that allow me to make sure that the data will not decrypted unless tow keys decryted the data.....

Comment: I want to make a secure e-voting by use two different keys.... that allow me to make sure that the data will not decrypted unless tow keys exist …..
When the first encrypt data has been accomplished by using the first key .. I'll make a second encrypt again by using the second key to encrypt the first step  
please Advice.

Comment: This is not a new problem and you'll find a **lot** of literature about this by googling. One way is to encrypt data using a random symmetric key (e.g. 256bits AES) and the first half (128 bits) with RSA-1 and the second half (128 bits) with RSA-2.